# why the program won't compile?

Tags: c++, g++

I don't get it why this simple code won't compile! All I trying to do is to create an array of pointers to the object of type Set.

```
int main()
{
    size_t n = 0;
    size_t ops = 0;
    cin >> n >> ops;
    Set ** arr = new Set*[n+1];
    for (size_t i = 1; i< n+1; ++i) {
        Set s = new Set(i);
        arr[i] = &s;
    }
```

Above I have my Set type definition:

```
struct Set
{
    Set (size_t x) {
        this->p = x;
        this->rank = 0;
        this->index = x;
}

    size_t index;
    size_t p;
    size_t rank;
};
```

But when g++ does't accept this code as correct and here's what it's saying:

```
dss.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

dss.cpp:57:20: error: invalid conversion from ‘Set*’ to ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-fpermissive]
   Set s = new Set(i);
                    ^

dss.cpp:17:2: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Set::Set(size_t)’ [-fpermissive]
  Set (size_t x) {
  ^
```

What is it talking about? what converion? Soorry, but I can't see any convertion!!  What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Did you come to c++ after another language? It looks like you are doing ruby-ish things in c++.

Comment: @JohnDibling I don't know ruby, but I programmed some on php and javaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set s = new Set(i);
arr[i] = &s;
```

should be

```
Set *s = new Set(i);
arr[i] = s;
```

or simply

```
arr[i] = new Set(i);
```

and you probably want to start loop from `i = 0`

Comment: but why?? Did i miss that new Set(i) already return pointer to an object by default?

Comment: @dKab Yes, `new` returns a non-null pointer in your case `'s'` wasn't a pointer.

Comment: I should have known that, and yes I am aware that loops usually start from 0 but in this case there are reasons to start from 1